# Counting frequency using plyr

Tags: r, count, combinations, frequency

I'm trying to use the `count` function from the library `plyr` in R to calculate the frequency of specific combinations of numbers that showed up.

For example, I want to know exactly how often number 1 and 2 showed up together.

```
   N1 N2 N3 
1   1  2  5
2   2  1  4    
3   2  4  3
4   3  1  2    
5   2  3  1
6   3  1  4
```

So for a dataframe like the one above, I had to combine column 1 and column 2, column 1 and 3, column 2 and 3, and merge all of them. Then I do the "count" for the merged dataframe.

```
combined1_2 = cbind(df$N1,df$N2)
combined1_3 = cbind(df$N1,df$N3)
combined2_3 = cbind(df$N2,df$N3)

combined_all = rbind(freq1_2,freq1_3,freq2_3)
combined_freq = count(combined_all)
```

So when I check the frequency table, I got the following result (only partial result is shown).

```
  x1 x2  Freq
1  1  2     2
2  2  1     2
```

The problem is that the count function treated number "1 and 2" different from "2 and 1". So I was wondering if there is any function in R that can solve this problem and produce the right result like the one below.

```
  x1 x2  Freq
1  1  2     4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just count the times the numbers are together in a row:

```
sum(apply(df, 1, function(x){all(c(1, 2) %in% x)}))
#[1] 4
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! It saves the process of having to combine each column. I was wondering if there is a simple way of writing out all combinations between any two numbers among 1 and 40. Or is using a loop the only solution to replace the c(1, 2) part to c(i, i+n)?

Comment: @1stclassmelon you're welcome :-). Maybe with `combn` for your second question ?

Answer (score 3):

You could also vectorize this if there are not too many numbers to check by just checking if `df` equals to each of the numbers

```
sum((rowSums(df == 1) > 0) & (rowSums(df == 2) > 0))
## [1] 4
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. This really simplifies the process. An additional question: for larger data, I guess I will have to use a loop if I want to find the combination frequency among, for example, 40 different numbers?

Comment: If you have 40 different numbers, use Caths method, it will be simpler